# Find a string in a list of list in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a nested list as below:

```
[['asgy200;f','ssll100','   time is: 10h:00m:12s','xxxxxxx','***','','asgy200;f','frl5100','   time is: 00h:00m:05s','ooo']]
```

`'***'` is my delimiter. I want to separate all of seconds in the list in python.
First of all with regular expression I want to separate the line that has `time is:` string but it doesn't work!

I don't know what should I do.

Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I just want to check if all seconds are not equal to 00.

Comment: could you provide the expected output? So that it would be easy for us to help.

Comment: output is: 12 and 5. Actually I should check seconds in a loop  and if all of them are !=00 then return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
x=[['asgy200;f','ssll100','time is: 10h:00m:12s','xxxxxxx','***','','asgy200;f','frl5100','time is: 00h:00m:05s','ooo']]
s=str(x)
print re.findall(r"(?<=time is)\s*:\s*[^']*:(\d+)",s)
```

Output:`['12', '05']`

You can try this.

Comment: I use your code but it doesn't work for me. I checked my list and I notice that before _time is:_ i have some spaces. I erase spaces manually and then it works. Sorry to not say about spaces.What should i do with this spaces?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a look-ahead regex (`r'(?<=time is\:).*'`) :

```
>>> [i.group(0).split(':')[2] for i in [re.search(r'(?<=time is\:).*',i) for i in l[0]] if i is not None]
['12s', '05s']
```

and you can convert them to int :

```
>>> [int(j.replace('s','')) for j in sec]
[12, 5]
```

if you want the string of seconds don't convert them to int after replace :

```
>>> [j.replace('s','') for j in sec]
['12', '05']
```

Comment: Thanks but this code doesn't work for me and the out pt should not have _s_ postfix.Thanks

Comment: @F.M You're welcome , Do you want seconds with the string format like `'12', '05'` ? also i added how get the int value of those !

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing groups also. It won't print the seconds if the seconds is exactly equal to `00`

```
>>> lst = [['asgy200;f','ssll100','time is: 10h:00m:12s','xxxxxxx','***','','asgy200;f','frl5100','time is: 00h:00m:05s','ooo']]
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'time\s+is:\s+\d{2}h:\d{2}m:(\d{2})', ' '.join(lst[0])) if int(i) != 00]
['12', '05']
>>> lst = [['asgy200;f','ssll100','time is: 10h:00m:00s','xxxxxxx','***','','asgy200;f','frl5100','time is: 00h:00m:05s','ooo']]
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'time\s+is:\s+\d{2}h:\d{2}m:(\d{2})', ' '.join(lst[0])) if int(i) != 00]
['05']
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your last comment to your Q,

```
>>> x = [['asgy200;f','ssll100','time is: 10h:00m:12s','xxxxxxx','***','','asgy200;f','frl5100','time is: 00h:00m:05s','ooo']]
>>> print all([w[-3:-1]!='00' for r in x for w in r if w.startswith('time is: ')])
True
>>>
```

`all` and `any` are two useful builtins...

The thing operates like this, the slower loop is on the sublists (`r`ows) of x, the fastest loop on the items (`w`ords)in each `r`ow, we pick up only the words that `startswith` a specific string, and our iterable is made of booleans where we have true if the 3rd last and 2nd last character of the picked word are different from`'00'`. Finally the `all` consumes the iterable and returns `True` if all the second fields are different from `'00'`.

HTH,

#### Addendum

Do we want to break out early?

```
all_secs_differ_from_0 = True

for row in x:
    for word in row:
        if word.startswith('time is: ') and word[-3:-1] == '00':
            all_secs_differ_from_0 = False
            break
    if not all_secs_differ_from_0: break
```

Comment: @F.M Re your _late_ clarification: please change `'time is: '` with `'   time is: '`